# Spring Integration premature end of file exception when trying to process some RSS feeds

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using Spring Integration and it's [Feed Inbound Channel Adaptor](https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/) to ingest RSS feeds. I've been looking at the log files and I can see quite a few errors with premature end of file exception when trying to process some of the feeds.

An example feed that produces the error is: 
http://www.france24.com/en/rss

I used the [getting starting guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/) to see if I could replicate with this feed url and this is the full exception being thrown.

```
2019-02-05 15:57:08.719 ERROR 30890 --- [ask-scheduler-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to retrieve feed for 'FeedEntryMessageSource{feedUrl=http://www.france24.com/en/top-stories/rss, feedResource=null, metadataKey='news.http://www.france24.com/en/top-stories/rss', lastTime=-1}'; nested exception is com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Premature end of file.
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:247)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.populateEntryList(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:210)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.doReceive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:185)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.receive(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:151)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:243)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:262)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.lambda$run$0(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:391)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:385)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.rometools.rome.io.ParsingFeedException: Invalid XML: Error on line 1: Premature end of file.
        at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:236)
        at com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput.build(SyndFeedInput.java:150)
        at org.springframework.integration.feed.inbound.FeedEntryMessageSource.getFeed(FeedEntryMessageSource.java:234)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Premature end of file.
        at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:232)
        at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:303)
        at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1196)
        at com.rometools.rome.io.WireFeedInput.build(WireFeedInput.java:233)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1014)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
        at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:217)
        ... 24 more
```

Are these types of feeds supported? If so, anything I need to change to process them or is this something to do with ROME.

**Configuration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
        xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
        xmlns:feed="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/feed/spring-integration-feed.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd">

    <feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="news" url="http://www.techradar.com/rss" auto-startup="${auto.startup:true}">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:transformer
            input-channel="news"
            expression="payload.title + ' @ ' + payload.link + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'"
            output-channel="file"/>

    <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="file"
            mode="APPEND"
            charset="UTF-8"
            directory="/tmp/si"
            filename-generator-expression="'${feed.file.name:SpringBlog}'"/>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally worked it out. When we started processing these feeds, some of them were being served over http and now they are 302 redirected to https. The Rome fetch doesn't follow the redirect and causes the exception. I didn't realise as I was checking the feeds in my browser which were automatically redirecting. If I change the feeds to https, they start working!

Would be super useful if the redirect is followed as opposed to throwing an exception. Not sure if the enhancement could be made in Spring Integration as content fetching seems to be deprecated in ROME.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So54538809Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54538809Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() throws MalformedURLException {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(feeder(), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(15_000).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))
                .transform("payload.description.value")
                .handle(System.out::println)
                .get();
    }

    private FeedEntryMessageSource feeder() throws MalformedURLException {
        return new FeedEntryMessageSource(new URL("https://www.france24.com/en/rss"), "so54538809");
    }

}
```

and

```
GenericMessage [payload=A jailed football player who has refugee status in Australia told a Thai court Monday that he refuses to be voluntarily extradited to Bahrain, which has asked for his return to serve a prison sentence for a crime he denies committing., headers={id=1491b285-529e-53ae-eafe-4a454150712b, timestamp=1549385470622}]
```

Comment: How odd. I ran it a couple of times and it started working. Could it be to do something to do with how long a RSS page takes to respond? If it doesn't receive the page in time it or its mid receiving the response it throws an error? I was able to just reproduce the same error with http://www.techradar.com/rss but it might be intermittent. I'll post the configuration i'm using above.

Comment: It's probably some kind of intermittent network issue; It looks like Rome just delegates the XML parsing to the SAX parser, which is throwing the error due to an incomplete document.

Comment: OK thanks. Who does the fetch of the feed Spring or Rome? I read that it may be deprecated in Rome to do the fetch which may be causing the error. If it's Spring, is there anything I can configure to make it wait a little longer?

Comment: Spring delegates to a Rome `XmlReader`. I am not familiar with it but you might be able to use a custom `URLStreamHandler` in the URL. However, `Premature end of file.` implies the socket was closed, so a longer wait probably won't help.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I'll take a look. I'm getting about 5000 of these per day so need to find a workaround.